# Create a dll in powerbuilder 12.5

Tags: dll, powerbuilder

I would like to create a dll in PowerBuilder 12.5 to use in PowerBuilder 6 or in another programing language. I've been searching how to do that, but I only find how to export a dll made in C++ (as an example) to use in PowerBuilder. Anybody knows if is it possible to do what I'm looking for?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18065300/62576

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply generate DLLs to be called from other languages or other PB releases.

Reason:
PowerBuilder compiles to its own P-code VM (like Java compiles to JVM). PB machine code is still "non-exposed" code despite hiding in a DLL file.

However, PB 12.5 can generate "wrappers" to encapsulate PB non-visual classes as .NET assemblies or .NET web services (ref: PowerBuilder's "Deploying Applications and Components to .NET")

PB 6 released in 1997 is pre-pretty-much-everything. Unaware of Java, .NET, web-services, and Unicode. Migrate any PB 6 code to a recent PB release, like PB 2017.